# Pandas Styler object has no attribute hide index error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

[image]

I am trying to [hide the index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html) with:

```
df.style.hide_index()
```

But I am getting the following error: `AttributeError: 'Styler' object has no attribute 'hide_index'`

Any suggestions on how to correct this error?
THANK YOU!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pandas documentation for Styler says

> Provisional: This is a new feature and still under development. We’ll
>   be adding features and possibly making breaking changes in future
>   releases. We’d love to hear your feedback.

So it could be that the version of Pandas you are using is breaking it from working.

Answer (score 4):

Check the version of Pandas that you are using. This function has changed in version 1.3.0 from:

```py
df.style.hide_index()
```

to

```py
df.style.hide()
```

More info in Pandas official documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.hide_index.html).